# Why is my return symbol broken in Pharo, throwing Unknown character error when compiling method?

Tags: keyboard, smalltalk, pharo

I'm starting at the [Pharo MOOC](https://mooc.pharo.org/), but got stuck in one of the first lessons, because apparently my return operator is broken. I faced this problem in the section [ReDo1] Packages, Classes and Methods. At one point, we are supposed to define a simple method, a getter, like this:

[image]

By when I try to follow the lesson in my Pharo install, the return "hat" operator ^ is a bit different, and smaller. When I try to compile the method, I just get a error:

[image]

[image]

But I'm pretty sure I typed the correct character in my keyboard, as the photo shows:

[image]

Could the problem be related to my keyboard layout. I run Pharo 8 using a ABNT2 keyboard (for pt-BR) under Kubuntu 20.04.

UPDATE: Adding image of entire keyboard, as requested by Leandro. It's a Philips C324 (ABNT standard):
[image]

Comment: There are two cicumflex characters $^ and $ˆ. The first one has code point 94 (5E), the second 710 (2C6). Pharo accepts $^ but does not recognizes the latter. The problem seems to be in your keyboard, not in Pharo. What do you get when you type that character in a regular text editor? Also, could you show us the entire keyboard?

Comment: Thank you Leandro. I edited the question to add the requested information on the keyboard. On typing the character here, I get this: ^. I actually figured out what was the problem. Pretty silly one. I will post as a answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You must double tap the circumflex key.

I figured out the problem. It's just that when I press Shift and single tap the circumflex key, at first I get nothing, then I get the character not recognized in the next keypress (usually spacebar), the code point 710 (2C6) mentioned by Leandro. If after pressing Shift I double tap the circumflex key, I get the correct character, code point 94 (5E).

Comment: Have you tried Shift+^+Space? In my US International keyboard configuration Shift+^ will print nothing until I press the next key. If it is a vowel, say a, it will print â, if it is not (say Space) it will print ^. Perhaps you have something similar that generates diacritics.

Comment: My situation was just the one you described. The wrong ^ was printed only at next keypress. I forgot to mention this detail in the answer. Will fix it.

Comment: Thank you, @tukan. I thought I could only accept answers from other people, not my own.